# Adding Item to Sharepoint online List creates empty Items using GRAPH API V1

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am testing a proof concept to use GRAPH API with a SharePoint Online (SP) site created via MS Teams. I have a simple list on the Site, which I have populated 2 records directly in SP for testing purposes and I am looking to test simple CRUD actions, using POSTMAN. The longer term goal is to use an automation program (BPA Platform) to use it Web Service tool to retrieve this data for storage in an onsite SQL db for other business systems to use. It is likely the SP List will have a low code solution over the top as a user interface (probably PowerApps) and therefore all the help needs to just use HTTPS calls and not another code solution, thank you.

The authentication root I have used so far is Azure App to create a App secret and assign that app correct permission
[image: image of app permissions in azure]

The SP List has the following definition of columns
[image: image of column definition of the test list]

I am able to retrieve the items of the list with the call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{IT_Testing_Id}}/lists/{{ListID}}/items?expand=fields
```

The return is (I have only shown the fields)

```
"fields": {
            "@odata.etag": "\"1512bad7-b01f-494d-924c-88c44104cae2,1\"",
            "Title": "Apple",
            "LinkTitleNoMenu": "Apple",
            "LinkTitle": "Apple",
            "Ref": "1",
            "Number": 2.0,
            "DateTest": "2023-10-30T00:00:00Z",
            "PartNo": "1010910.A",
            "LookupLookupId": "1",
            "id": "1",
            "ContentType": "Item",
            "Modified": "2023-11-02T08:50:53Z",
            "Created": "2023-11-02T08:50:53Z",
            "AuthorLookupId": "9",
            "EditorLookupId": "9",
            "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
            "Attachments": false,
            "Edit": "",
            "ItemChildCount": "0",
            "FolderChildCount": "0",
            "_ComplianceFlags": "",
            "_ComplianceTag": "",
            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
            "_ComplianceTagUserId": ""
        }
    },
        
    "fields": {
            "@odata.etag": "\"4c1a4755-1e58-4bac-b04f-f3270d8aed03,1\"",
            "Title": "Orange",
            "LinkTitleNoMenu": "Orange",
            "LinkTitle": "Orange",
            "Ref": "2",
            "Number": 5.0,
            "DateTest": "2023-11-02T00:00:00Z",
            "PartNo": "1020020",
            "LookupLookupId": "2",
            "id": "2",
            "ContentType": "Item",
            "Modified": "2023-11-02T08:56:09Z",
            "Created": "2023-11-02T08:56:09Z",
            "AuthorLookupId": "9",
            "EditorLookupId": "9",
            "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
            "Attachments": false,
            "Edit": "",
            "ItemChildCount": "0",
            "FolderChildCount": "0",
            "_ComplianceFlags": "",
            "_ComplianceTag": "",
            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
            "_ComplianceTagUserId": ""
        }
    },
```

However, the issue is on the POST, when I complete the POST I get a status of `201 Created`

However in SP I see this:

[image: image on sharepoint list after post]

I believe I am not sending the correct information in my Post command.

here are the details of the post

Post command call
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{IT_Testing_Id}}/lists/{{ListID}}/items](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BIT_Testing_Id%7D%7D/lists/%7B%7BListID%7D%7D/items)

Header details

```
 {
            "Title": "Pear",
            "Ref": "25",
            "Number": 2.0,
            "DateTest": "2023-10-30T00:00:00Z",
            "PartNo": "5000000.A"
            }
```

The response is

```
"fields": {
    "@odata.etag": "\"038843b1-b587-441b-aa90-a8cef5e53c28,1\"",
    "Number": 0.0,
    "DateTest": "2023-11-03T11:43:58Z",
    "id": "15",
    "ContentType": "Item",
    "Modified": "2023-11-03T11:43:58Z",
    "Created": "2023-11-03T11:43:58Z",
    "AuthorLookupId": "1073741822",
    "EditorLookupId": "1073741822",
    "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
    "Attachments": false,
    "Edit": "",
    "ItemChildCount": "0",
    "FolderChildCount": "0",
    "_ComplianceFlags": "",
    "_ComplianceTag": "",
    "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
    "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
    "AppAuthorLookupId": "10",
    "AppEditorLookupId": "10"
}
```

notice the id has moved on but the data is empty

Can anyone suggest any things to try please? I am guessing that I am not supplying the correct header information / format?

my main references have been
[Getting Started with Graph API and Graph Explorer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/getting-started-with-graph-api-and-graph-explorer/)
[Overview of Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields names must be inside the `fields` property when sending POST request.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Pear",
    "Ref": "25",
    "Number": 2.0,
    "DateTest": "2023-10-30T00:00:00Z",
    "PartNo": "5000000.A"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as a check ask what is the format for POSTing to a SP lookup field?

Comment: @IanW Probably "<fieldName>LookupId": "10" Try to use field name and add LookupId. Example: if you have Person lookup filed then "PersonLookupId": "10"